# pass pointer back to main from function in c

Tags: c

I have looked through the previous posts, and I do not see anything similar to what I am doing. I am trying to pass a pointer from a function back to main. Here is what I have...

```
#include <stdio.h>
char* monthName ()
{
char month [20] = "January";
char* pMonth;
pMonth = month;
printf("Printing month from monthName function %s\n", month);
/*while (*pMonth != '\0')
  {
    putch(*pMonth);
    pMonth++;
  }*/
return pMonth;
}
int main (void)
{
char* monthName();
char* currentMonth;
currentMonth = monthName();
putch('\n');
while (*currentMonth != '\0')
  {
    putch(*currentMonth);
    currentMonth++;
  }
}
```

Here is the gdb output

```
Breakpoint 1, monthName () at 132.c:4
4       char month [20] = "January";
(gdb) n
6       pMonth = month;
(gdb) n
7       printf("Printing month from monthName function %s\n", month);
(gdb) p pMonth
$7 = 0x61fee8 "January"
(gdb) n
Printing month from monthName function January
13      return pMonth;
(gdb) p pMonth
$8 = 0x61fee8 "January"
(gdb) n
14      }
(gdb) p pMonth
$9 = 0x61fee8 "January"
(gdb) n
main () at 132.c:20
20      putch('\n');
(gdb) p pMonth
No symbol "pMonth" in current context.
(gdb) q
A debugging session is active.

        Inferior 1 [process 7836] will be killed.

Quit anyway? (y or n) y
error return ../../gdb-7.6.1/gdb/windows-nat.c:1275 was 5
```

Comment: You can't return a pointer t a local variable with an automatic storage class! And "something similar" is popping out here every second question.

Comment: `char month [20] = "January";` is a local (automatic) variable. It goes out of scope when the function returns, so returning a pointer to it is *undefined behaviour*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem may be that you return a local variable. That variable can be overwritten once you leave the method that created it and the stack grows to the location where it was allocated.

Instead, you should look into `malloc()` and `free()` for allocating persistent memory that will not be reclaimed after leaving the method.

Some documentation: http://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-dynamic-memory-allocation

Comment: There are no methods in C.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to allocate  a local character array in main and pass that to the the function and have the function strcpy or memcpy into the buffer and use the returned value (note that you really want to probably use the strcpyn or memcpyn (if I am remembering the function name right) to limit the data copied to lenght specified (to avoid buffer overrun,  n could be based in as length of buffer.